# Improve performance of a rest resource

Tags: apex, rest-api, apexrest, performance, restresource

I have a rest resource which fetches more than 10000 records. iterates the list using foreach and adds each record to a custom wrapper class list and finally returns the custom wrapper list as response. when I hit this API with post man. It takes more than 4 seconds to get the response. is there any way to improve the performance?

What are some general best practices to improve the performance of a rest api in apex.

please find the code below.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/custom_info/*')
global class custom_Service{

    @HttpGet
    Webservice static void getAssetListForSelectedUser(){
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;

        customWrapper result; 
        String federationId=req.params.get('recid');
        String pageSize = req.params.get('limit');
        String pageNumber = req.params.get('offset');

        User usr = new User();
        usr = [Select Id, Name, LanguageLocaleKey from User where FederationIdentifier = :federationId];

        List<Asset__c> assets = [Select Id, Name, createddate, serial__c, Field_one__c,Field_two__c,Field_three__c, Field_four__c, Field_five__c, Field_six__c Description__c from Asset__c where ownerId = : usr.id];

        result = new customWrapper(usr.name, usr.LanguageLocaleKey, assets);

        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(result));
        return;
    }

    global class customWrapper {
        public String name{get;set;}
        public String language{get;set;}
        public List<innerWrapper> astList{get;set;}

        public customWrapper(){}

        public customWrapper (String name, String lan, List<Asset__c> assets) {
            name = name;
            language = lan;
            for (Asset__c a : assets) {
                astList.add(new innerWrapper(a));
            }
        }
    }

    global class inner wrapper {
        public String name{get;set;}
        public String createdDate{get;set;}
        public String serial{get;set;}
        public String Field_one__c{get;set;}
        public String Field_two__c{get;set;}
        public String Field_three__c{get;set;}
        public String Field_four__c{get;set;}
        public String Field_five__c{get;set;}
        public String Field_six__c{get;set;}

        public innerWrapper(){}

        public innerWrapper(List<Asset__c> assets) {
            name = assets.name;
            createdDate = assets.createdDate;
            serial = assets.serial__c;
            fieldOne = assets.Field_one__c;
            fieldTwo = assets.Field_two__c;
            fieldThree = assets.Field_three__c;
            fieldFour = assets.Field_four__c;
            fieldFive = assets.Field_five__c;
            fieldSix = assets.Field_six__c;
        }
    }
}
```

please help.

Comment: Can you include your code? That would be a good start to allow specific responses on what you have written. One immediate thing to try is that a for(Integer i=0...) loop is faster than for(SObject o in list)

Comment: @Aidan I am working on that for loop with integer. please go through my code and let me know if it can me optimized.

Comment: FYI, do not use `webservice` when you mean `global`. This might confuse some developers who read your code later. `webservice` means you want to call this method with SOAP instead of REST, but you're using REST-only properties.

Comment: One possibility to consider: with 10k or more rows, even if your fields average a mere 8 ASCII characters, you're still looking at multiple _megabits_ of data that you're trying to transfer. If your internet connection only gives you 1 Mbps download speed, then refactoring/optimizing your code will only give limited improvement (you'll start receiving data faster, but you'd still need to wait for all of it to be transferred).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Processing server-side will always cost performance. The best performance would be if you could return the data without a wrapper. Failing that, the next best option would be to optimize the code.

Several optimizations when you're talking about 10k+ items follow.

## Pre-Initialize Arrays

Using List.add is relatively expensive. You can save that per-item cost with one upfront heap allocation:

```
Integer queryResultsSize = queryResults.size();
Wrapper[] results = new Wrapper[queryResultsSize];
```

In your loop, you then:

```
Wrapper temp = new Wrapper();
// populate temp //
// then add to list //
results[i] = temp;
```

## Calculate Size Only Once

Many developers write this:

```
for(Integer i = 0; i < queryResults.size(); i++) {
```

You'll get better performance with:

```
for(Integer i = 0, s = queryResults.size(); i < s; i++) {
```

The difference is minimal for small lists, but really adds up when you're talking about tens of thousands of method calls.

## Minimize Field Copies

If you need a wrapper, if you can at least reuse the record, you'll get better performance:

```
public class Wrapper {
  public String someValue;
  public Boolean someFlag;
  public sObject someRecord;
}
```

Is better than:

```
public class Wrapper {
  public String field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6;
  public Boolean field7, field8, field9, field10;
  public Date field11, field12, field13, field14, field15, field16;
  // ... etc ... //
}
```

Every field you have to set costs you CPU and wall-clock time.

## Use Automatic Serialization

```
@HttpGet global static Wrapper[] doGet() {
  Wrapper[] results; // ... populate results //
  return results;
}
```

Is faster than:

```
@HttpGet global static void doGet() {
  Wrapper[] results; // ... populate results //
  RestContext.response.responseBody = JSON.serialize(results);
}
```

And:

```
@HttpGet global static String doGet() {
  Wrapper[] results; // ... populate results //
  return JSON.serialize(results);
}
```

The system is much more efficient when you let it serialize for you. The downside, of course, is you lose some control over exactly how the results are serialized.

Using a method return value also has the advantage of switching from JSON to XML by changing the Accept header with no further modification to your Apex.